# Unidentified command in linux top command result

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, top-command

We have developed an app and hosted on linux (aws) with 50 gb hard disk and 16 gb of ram (t2.xlarge).

We found even in the moderate traffic cpu usage goes up to around 80%

When we tried to check the memory usage through terminal we found around 15gb of ram has been utilised. To check ram/CPU usage, I tried with top command

here is the output of top command. I am not able to understand cpu usage by command named wnTKYg. Please help me out in this.

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

**19756 root      20   0  374m 9916 1844 S 299.7  0.1 483:13.13 wnTKYg**

27645 apache    20   0  442m  25m  12m S  2.7  0.2   0:00.08 httpd
23046 ec2-user  20   0 1208m  60m  20m S  1.0  0.4   1:30.84 node
27493 apache    20   0  531m  37m  17m S  0.7  0.2   0:01.63 httpd
 2434 root      20   0 13720 1608 1392 S  0.3  0.0   0:46.58 irqbalance
 2760 root      20   0  428m  25m  16m S  0.3  0.2   1:26.54 httpd
27647 apache    20   0  436m  18m 9772 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.01 httpd
27651 apache    20   0  436m  19m  10m S  0.3  0.1   0:00.01 httpd

I was not able to find any similar question/answer on stackoverflow, please guide  me in this.

Comment: Ok, we talked with aws support guy and he told , somehow our system is infected with malware. The only solution as per their suggestion is to stop this instance and deploy code (from scratch) on another instance.